# Fuse Project in JBoss Developer Studio

Tags: jboss, fuseesb, jboss-developer-studio

I'm new in JBoss Developer Studio. 
Where I can find example, how I can make fuse integration project and RUN it on server? I cann't run my test project on server, I see a lot of errors, but my project consist only LOG component. And Why I cann't run this project on EAP 7.1 or Fuse 6.3?

i have JBoss EAP 7.1 and JBoss Fuse 6.3.

Thank you in advance, and sorry for my English)

Offtop:
When I use Mule, I can make and run my first project for 10-15 minutes. But in Developer Studio it's very... difficult. I wasted 2 days without result

Comment: way to go mule! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry that you are facing problems.

I would suggest you try to read the documentation at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/pdf/tooling_tutorials/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse-6.3-Tooling_Tutorials-en-US.pdf . It is a good starting point for writing camel routes with the JBoss Fuse Tooling. I would also recommend you learn more about Apache Camel at http://camel.apache.org as the tooling is for Camel.

Hope that helps,
Lars